# What is the difference - 'is doing' vs 'does'?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Could you please explain what is the difference between the followings and when one of them should be used instead of the another?

> My brother **is doing** a degree at university so I don't see him very
>   often, unfortunately.
>
> My brother **does** a degree at university so I don't see him very
>   often, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to add that "my brother is getting a degree" is a temporary situation, usually lasting a few years and that is why the present continuous is required. The present simple is used for permanent situations.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the verb tense part of the question.

Comment: Just one clarification. How long should last some event to be surely used in present tense?

Comment: Being a student is temporary, even though it lasts a few years, but you can`t be a student for 20 years. You can live in a country your whole life, or hold a job for 20 years. Then you would say I live in or I work as.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these are correct. Usually you would instead write:

> *My brother is getting a degree at university, so I don't seem him very often unfortunately.*

***is getting*** implies the action is still in progress. He is still in the action of getting the degree.

I followed your sentence structure, but I think it would be better written:

> *My brother is getting a degree at university, so unfortunately I don't see him very often.*

This sentence just flows a little nicer than the original.

Answer (score 0):

For the record (as a native English speaker) I don't think there is anything wrong with saying **"My brother is doing a degree"**. The phrase "**getting a degree"** would be more likely to be used when referring to future plans. For example

> "My bucket list includes getting a degree"

rather than something which is happening in the present. In the present tense you would say

> "I am doing a degree".

Comment: Edit: This may be an American/British English distinction. I am from England and the above is correct as regards British English.

Comment: Please note that you can [edit] your answer by clicking the edit link underneath.